# Form Validation on CodeIgniter Cart page

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-2, shopping-cart

CodeIgniter v2.1.2

I have a very simple CodeIgniter shopping cart page setup as per [the CodeIgniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html).

This Cart page shows however many products are in the shopping cart and the `input` elements for editing the quantity of each have `name` attributes assigned as follows:  `1[qty]`, `2[qty]`, `3[qty]`, `4[qty]`, `5[qty]`, etc.

```
<input name="1[qty]" type="text" ...
<input name="2[qty]" type="text" ...
<input name="3[qty]" type="text" ...
<input name="4[qty]" type="text" ...
<input name="5[qty]" type="text" ...
....
```

This is the scheme as per the CodeIgniter documentation and it seems to work well because the POST array is automatically in the correct format for easily updating the cart.

```
$this->cart->update( $this->input->post() );
```

It seems that the `cart->update()` will ignore any invalid input.  In other words, the cart only updates when the quantities are numeric values.  However, I think I need to apply CodeIgniter form validation to the cart page.  Maybe I don't need it and interested in your thoughts on this too.

In my Controller, where I would normally set the rules *by field name* using `set_rules`, I have no idea what goes in the field `name` parameter when I have an unknown number of fields.

The [documentation says I can declare validation on arrays](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html/#arraysasfields), but I cannot get the following code to work for me.  I've tried `[qty]`, `[][qty]` and a few others.  By not working, I mean there are no validation errors on the quantity fields on the Cart page when they contain invalid data and it always passes validation and hits the `update()` function.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('[][qty]', 'Quantity', 'numeric|strip_tags|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) // passed validation -> submission
{
    // update the cart
    $this->cart->update( $this->input->post() );
    ....
}
else
{
    // display validation errors
    ....
}
```

- How can I apply validation to the cart page when the number of fields is dynamic and naming is as described above?
- Do I even need validation of the quantity fields?  The cart data is temporarily stored in the session, and when it's passed into the `cart->update()` function, invalid data seems to be stripped out automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not figure out how to declare validation on an array, I used a `for` loop to declare the rule on every "QTY" field based on the number of unique line items in the cart as per the value of `count($this->cart->contents())`.  *(As opposed to `$this->cart->total_items()` which counts everything including multiples of a single line item.)*

In the **Controller**...

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($this->cart->contents()); $i++)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($i . '[qty]', 'Item #' . $i . ' quantity', 'numeric|strip_tags|xss_clean');
}
```

---

I still cannot confirm if form validation is needed in this case.  Typically, server-side validation is required to protect the database from bad data or for security.  In this case, the `cart->update()` function seems to reject invalid entries automatically.